# Raspberry Pi local wordpress unreachable

Tags: wordpress, apache, raspberry-pi, wordpress-theming

I've been working on a local WordPress site on a raspberry pi for a few weeks now, and suddenly the site is "unreachable" anywhere on the network, including on the raspberry pi. I get the same errors whether I try to access through "localhost" or "192.168.0.110".

I checked the apache2 status, and it seems to be running correctly. I also checked the ssh status, which claims to be running correctly too, but I cannot ssh into the device anymore from another computer.

After looking into it, the only thing I could see that may have caused this is installing some plugins that have weird security aspects. I did install 2 very common, non-security related plugins recently, but even after deleting them in the WordPress files, the WordPress site is still unreachable (I did not change anything else about the WordPress code/files besides deleting those recently added plugins).

Does anyone know something else that could be causing this issue? I have been using the "Semplice" theme to set up the site, but that has not caused any issues for the past few months and nothing has changed with that between it working and breaking. I really don't want to lose all the content I've been working on for it. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here are sections of code that may be helpful:

apache2.conf:

```
apache2.conf
T
Type
Text
Size
7 KB (7,224 bytes)
Storage used
14 KB (14,448 bytes)
Location
apache2
Owner
me
Modified
Nov 20, 2020 by me
Opened
3:55 PM by me
Created
Nov 16, 2020 with Google Drive Web
Add a description
Viewers can download
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

ports.conf:

```
ports.conf
T
Type
Text
Size
320 bytes
Storage used
640 bytes
Location
apache2
Owner
me
Modified
Nov 20, 2020 by me
Opened
3:55 PM by me
Created
Nov 16, 2020 with Google Drive Web
Add a description
Viewers can download
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

000-default.conf in sites-enabled

```
000-default.conf
T
Type
Text
Size
1 KB (1,395 bytes)
Storage used
1 KB (1,395 bytes)
Location
sites-enabled
Owner
me
Modified
Sep 17, 2020 by me
Opened
3:56 PM by me
Created
Nov 20, 2020 with Google Drive Web
Add a description
Viewers can download
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

000-default.conf in sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

default-ssl.conf in sites-available

```
default-ssl.conf
T
Type
Text
Size
6 KB (6,338 bytes)
Storage used
12 KB (12,676 bytes)
Location
sites-available
Owner
me
Modified
Nov 20, 2020 by me
Opened
3:58 PM by me
Created
Nov 16, 2020 with Google Drive Web
Add a description
Viewers can download
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
        #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
        #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
        #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
        #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
        #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
        #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

        #   Client Authentication (Type):
        #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
        #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
        #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
        #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        #   SSL Engine Options:
        #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
        #   o FakeBasicAuth:
        #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
        #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
        #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
        #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
        #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
        #   o ExportCertData:
        #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
        #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
        #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
        #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
        #    into CGI scripts.
        #   o StdEnvVars:
        #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
        #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
        #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
        #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
        #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
        #   o OptRenegotiate:
        #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
        #    directives are used in per-directory context.
        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
        #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
        #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
        #    This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
        #    SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
        #    the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
        #    mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
        #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
        #    This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
        #    SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
        #    alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
        #    practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
        #    works correctly.
        #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
        #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
        #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
        #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
        #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
        #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
        # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        #       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        #       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Please provide specifics including the Apache configuration, Raspberry Pi configuration (related), etc. This is quite vague and requires much more information. Add your related code allowing folks to help by seeing what is happening.
NOTE: this certainly sounds like a networking issue, firewall blocking connections, configuration of Apache or WordPress, or several other things impossible to know without more information.

Comment: @fth I'm sorry, I set it up using [this] (https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress) tutorial. Here are all the versions/configurations I could find:

apache2 (2.4) (status active)
php 7.3.19-1~deb10u1 (cli)
mysql 15.1 Distrib 10.3.23-MariaDB (status active)
raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
wp_version =5.5.3, wp_db_version =48748

I checked my router status and it says the ip address for the server is connected to it (along with the actual raspberry pi). I looked through my firewall settings on my main cpu, nothing is on or has changed. Any other info?

Comment: this is helpful but not exactly what I meant. You must include actual code, such as the apache configuration file "/etc/apache2/apache.conf" and the site configuration file "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf", or whatever it is called. Further, please provide error messages, screenshots, and the like so that people may be able to aide in diagnosing your problem. Thanks.

Comment: One quick question, how is the Rasp Pi connected to the network? Is it via ethernet cable or WiFi? There is most likely a router setting limiting visibility of devices to each other. If the devices are on the same network and cannot see each other at all then apache is denying the request or the router is stopping it due to a setting. Alternatively if you have a firewall installed such as UFW then that could be denying access as well. More information please! :-)

Comment: @fth ok, [there] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1B4nDQHGAInwTsaOm0Lw32o8HyDB6_4dN?usp=sharing) is a copy of everything relevant should be in this google drive, please let me know if there is more I can add. The main errors I'm getting from the browser are "timeout" and "connection refused". Any time I try to ping the servers ip address, all packets are lost.

Comment: I am connected via wifi, but will try plugging in directly to the router to see if that changes anything. Strangely, from the routers admin page, yesterday I could see the exact IP address of the server connected to the router, along with the rasberry pi itself. Now, there is a different, but similar, ip address.

Comment: I tried connecting it directly, did not seem to make a difference. I also double checked for a firewall on the pi, it did not seem to have anything like that. I check for uwf and firewall-cmd, bother were not avaiable

Comment: Post code here for reference and not attach a whole set of files....

Comment: I'm sorry, but the code was taking up way too many characters to fit in here, even taking out all the comments.

Comment: Here are the code bits that I think would be the most relevant:

Comment: port.conf: 

# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

Comment: 000-default.conf:

<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
 

 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html

 # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
 # error, crit, alert, emerg.
 # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
 # modules, e.g.
 #LogLevel info ssl:warn

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Comment: Any code should be added via editing the question, not in the comments ... please edit the question and enter in 'code' sections so that it is formatted properly making it more easily read. For example, the question will have no problem displaying the Apache configurations. Most importantly familiarize yourself with the general rules here by reading the documentation. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq?tab=Votes

Comment: Ohhh, ok, I'm sorry I had no idea. I'll add those sections of code to the questions ASAP. Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ok, I have added the code to the main question, please let me know if there are any other files I can include.

Comment: So you are presently on step #3: Set up an Apache web server? If you are following that tutorial, did you verify Apache was running prior to the following steps? Please provide (and familiarize yourself with) the Apache logs: /var/log/apache2/error.log and /var/log/apache2/access.log.

Comment: No, I did the tutorial a while back and had everything completely finished and was making posts/designing the website. But then one day, the localhost just refused to connect and never came back on. I've checked the logs in the past and never found anything out of the ordinary. I'll double-check shortly to be sure, but I can't find anything wrong on the apache side of it.

I thought maybe a plugin I installed to wordpress caused this, but then I deleted the new plugin I added and it was still busted. At this point, I am planning to save as much as possible from the db and start from scratch

Comment: A quick setup (new, identical site pre-changes) the instructions you followed would be a nice way to do a comparison/diff with the dysfunctional one.  It would be for testing then removed. If this is not possible I'm sure we can find the issue. I need to revisit the site I been on other things.